# Use the CosmosDB Data Migration Tool to map a many-to-many relationship to a string array?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-cosmosdb, data-migration

I am migrating some data from Azure SQL into CosmosDB. I am using the CosmosDB Data Migration Tool. In the SQL Database I have a many-to-many relationship between Persons and Favorites. I want to migrate the Favorite Names into a simple array in the CosmosDB Document. I am not yet finding a way to do that. The documentation recommends that I use `FOR JSON AUTO` which converts the subquery into a JSON Array of Objects.

Below is the query as it stands now. This is not doing what I want.

```
SELECT 
    p.Id AS [id],
    p.FirstName AS [name.first],
    p.LastName AS [name.last],
    o.City AS [office.City],
    o.[State] AS [office.State], 
    c.ReminderEmailEnabled AS [reminderEmail], 
    (SELECT f.[Name] FROM dbo.Favorites f JOIN dbo.PersonFavorite pf ON pf.FavoriteId = f.Id AND pf.PersonId = p.Id  FOR JSON AUTO) AS [favorites]
FROM dbo.Persons p
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Offices o ON o.Id = p.OfficeId
```

Using this query the resulting JSON Document in CosmosDB looks like this:

```
{
    "name": {
        "first": "Donald",
        "last": "Duck"
    },
    "office": {
        "City": "Ann Arbor",
        "State": "MI"
    },
    "reminderEmail": true,
    "favorites": "[{\"Name\":\"Red\"},{\"Name\":\"Green\"}]",
    "id": "some guid",
}
```

It's turning it into a string which is why its then adding escape characters, and its an array of JSON objects.

What I want is:

```
{
    "name": {
        "first": "Donald",
        "last": "Duck"
    },
    "office": {
        "City": "Ann Arbor",
        "State": "MI"
    },
    "reminderEmail": true,
    "favorites": ["Red","Green"],
    "id": "some guid",
}
```

How can I modify my query to achieve this using the data migration tool?

Answer (score 0):

The Data Migration tool is not able to handle this but you can do this using ADF and Databricks. We wrote a blog post on this recently in our Cosmos DB blog.

[Migrating Relational Data into Azure Cosmos DB using Azure Data Factory and Azure Databricks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/migrating-relational-data-into-cosmos-db-using-azure-data-factory-and-azure-databricks/)

Hope this is helpful.